# Подставляются одинаковые значения autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Динамическая таблица по клику выпадают поля.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" id="tab_logic">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>.....</th>
   </tr>
 <tbody>
  <tr id='addr0'>
  <tr id='addr1'></tr>
 </tbody>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var product = ["<?php echo  $product; ?>"];
   var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
     $('#addr'+i).html("<td><input type='text' name='product_name[]' class='form'></td>" +
     .............
```

С помощью autocomplete в первом поле я сделал повыпадавший список у меня выбираться название товара. Я его отправляю на сервер там делаю выборку и мне возвращает название модели которое подставляю в это поле

`"<td><input name='model_product[]' class= 'model'  type='text></td>" +`

```
`$('#addr'+i).find('.form').autocomplete({ source:product,
   select: function(event, ui) {
    var product_name  = ui.item.value;
      console.log(product_name);
       $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/autocomplete',
         data:{ "name_product":product_name },
         success: function(data){
         $("input[name='model_product[]'").val(data);
        }
     });
   }
});
i++;`
```

Когда добавлен один товар то данные подставляются правильные, когда я добавляю еще один товар то модель подставляется и к первому и ко второму товару, подскажите как можно сделать что бы модель не изменялась.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

добавляю еще один товар

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выбора меняется название модели, в первом поле, можно ли как то сделать, что бы модель подставлялась только та которая соответствует выбранному товару?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я увидел из ваших кусков кода у вас много `input`-ов для продуктов (`<input name='model_product[]' class= 'model'  type='text>`), которые нечем не отличаются друг от друга.

Обясняю как работают селекторы в jQuery:

На вашем примере `$("input[name='model_product[]'")` - этот селектор выбирает набор элементов которые подходят вашим критериям, а если прямо с выборкой вы делаете какое то действие, то это действие влиять будет на весь набор выбранных элементов в селекторе.

Для того что бы вы могли взять один элемент из вашего набора дайте им такие классы или id которые будут для них уникальны, и с помощью них можете взять именно один элемент набора и действие будет влиять только на тот выбранный элемент.

**Простой пример:**

Есть несколько `input`

```
<input name='model_product[]' class= 'model1'  type='text>
<input name='model_product[]' class= 'model2'  type='text>
<input name='model_product[]' class= 'model3'  type='text>

`$('#addr'+i).find('.form').autocomplete({ source:product,
    select: function(event, ui) {
     var product_name  = ui.item.value;
       console.log(product_name);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/autocomplete',
          data:{ "name_product":product_name },
          success: function(data){
          $("input.model1").val(data);
         }
      });
    }
});
i++;`
```

Вот здесь уже селектор выберет только тот `input` у которого класс `model1` и действие произойдет только для него, остальные будут не тронуты.

Comment: А можно как то сделать что бы `class= 'model1'` был динамическим что бы при добавление новых `input` `class = model +1`

Comment: Да можно разными способами, смотря как вы реализовали ваше приложение.

Comment: задал переменную `var i=1;` а в самой таблице  `"<td><input name='model_product[]' class= 'model " +i  " ' type='text'></td>" +` 
так что не получается таблицу взял   bootstrap https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/pjW6O

Comment: @Sender1050 Давайте сделаем так, напишите новый вопрос и по пунктам скажите что вы хотите сделать, желательно и с куском бекенд кода, и я скажу как можно решить эту проблему, а то так мы долго спишемся и напрасно потеряем время.))))

Comment: Новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672686/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-js