# Как сделать динамический класс js

Tags: php, javascript

Таблица

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" id="tab_logic">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th><?php echo $text_product_name; ?></th>
     <th><?php echo $text_model; ?></th>
     <th><?php echo $text_sum_buy; ?></th>
     <th><?php echo $text_price; ?></th>
     <th><?php echo $text_count; ?></th>
     <th><?php echo $text_in_total; ?></th>
     <th><a id="add_row" ><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="<?php echo $text_add_product;?>"></a></th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr id='addr0'>
     <tr id='addr1'></tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var product = ["<?php echo  $product; ?>"];
var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td width='10%'><input type='text'  name='product_name[]' autocomplete='on' required class='form' ></td>" +
            "<td width='10%'><input name='model_product[]' class= 'model"+(i+1)+"' type='text'></td>" +
            "<td  width='20%'><input style='width:45%' type='text' name='price[]'> <input style='width:45%' readonly type='text' name='currency[]' ></td>"+
            "<td width='15%'><input type='text' name='total[]' style='width:90%'  id='i1'  ><input type='hidden' name='product_id[]'  class='form-control'  ></td>" +
            "<td width='10%'><img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/minus.png' border='0' onclick='jQuery(this).next().val(~~jQuery(this).next().val()-1); sum_total(this);'>" +
            "<input type='text' name='quantity[]' id=i2  value='0' size='1' >" +
            "<img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/plus.png' border='0' onclick='jQuery(this).prev().val(~~jQuery(this).prev().val()+1);sum_total(this);'></td>" +
            "<td width='10%'><input type='text'   name='oll_total[]' value='0' class=i3></td>" +
            "<td width='10%'><a id='delete_row' class=' minus' onclick='sum_delete(this)'><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='<?php echo $text_delete_product; ?>'></a></td></td>");
            $('#addr'+i).find('.form').autocomplete({ source:product,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    var product_name  = ui.item.value;
                    console.log(product_name);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/autocomplete',
                        data:{ "name_product":product_name },
                        success: function(data){
                            $("input.model").val(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            i++;
        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
$("#delete_row").click(function(){
    if(i > 1 ){
        $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
        i--;
    }
  });
});
  jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus', function(){
  jQuery( this ).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
});
```

Как сделать динамическими `class= 'model"+(i+1)+"'` что бы ответ вставлялся в нужный класс

```
success: function(data){
    $("input.model ").val(data);
}
```

Comment: Можно спросить ваш `ajax` запрос каждый раз возвращает только один продукт? И можете подчеркнуть в вашем написанном `html` коде где вы пишете слово, а где должно добавляться продукт.

Comment: Здесь  `<td width='10%'><input type='text'  name='product_name[]' autocomplete='on' required class='form' ></td>" +` я вожу название товара , а здесь вывод ` "<td width='10%'><input name='model_product[]' class= 'model"+(i+1)+"' type='text'></td>" +`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я понял что вы хотите сделать, Я добавлю только кусок кода вашего `autocomplete` и объясню мои изменения. И скажу, что вам не нужна переменная `var i`, ее можете стереть вообще.

```
$('#addr').find('.form').autocomplete({ source:product,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var product_name  = ui.item.value;
        var tmp_model_product = ui.item.parent().next().find('.model');
        console.log(product_name);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/autocomplete',
            data:{ "name_product":product_name },
            success: function(data){
                $(tmp_model_product).val(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

В своей поправке я сделал логику так, я при каждом изменении вашего левого  `input` ищу его правый `input` в котором нужно вставить значение, и сохраняю селектор для него (`var tmp_model_product = ui.item.next().find('.model');`).

А уже после возврата наших данных в `ajax` запросе делаю выборку нужного нам `input` уже сохраненным селектором. и вставляю значение в него.

И не забудьте везде где вы добавили переменную `+i` надо убрать, оно нам не нужно.